# How to get bash function return value in makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile

I source a bash script that contains a few functions under a makefile target. Then I call the bash function and try to get its return value via $?. It contains nothing. Therefore my questions is that in makefile, how to gets the bash function return value? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `$?` in makefile rule commands, you may like it to write it as `$$?`. Make expands the first dollar sign, hence it needs to be quoted.

Comment: gosh, that's the root cause which wasted me few hours.... :-( Any suggestion on returning a string besides the status value from a bash function inside makefile?

Comment: Not sure I understand your last question.

Comment: my_bash_function returns either 1 or 0 to tell whether the operation is succeed. If it returns 0, I also want it return a variable for example: RELEASE_TAG="VER_1.0". In the makefile, I want to first check $$? is 0, if that is true, I want to use $RELEASE_TAG, which should contains a string generated by "my_bash_function".

Comment: Output the string from the function and catch the output. If you specify `SHELL:=/bin/bash` in the Makefile, you can use `RELEASE_TAG=$$(function)`.

Comment: @WuwenLi: you can indicate failure by returning an empty string from the shell script (as long as empty sting is not a valid value). This way you wouldn't have to check both `$?` and `$RELEASE_TAG`.